# Facing a 403 Forbidden Error When Accessing Submission Manager on WordPress Site

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache2

I'm encountering a **403 Forbidden** error when attempting to access the [submission manager](https://github.com/devinemke/submgr) on my WordPress site hosted on a GoDaddy VPS server with Debian 11, Apache2, PHP, and MariaDB. The `submissions` directory has appropriate permissions (`drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 10 20:42 submissions`), and I've confirmed the issue with the following `curl` commands:

1. For submissions:

   ```
   curl -I https://aldenstreetreview.com/submissions/
   HTTP/2 403 
   date: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 19:07:18 GMT
   content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
   ```
2. For the main site:

   ```
   curl -I https://aldenstreetreview.com/
   HTTP/2 200 date: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 19:07:24 GMT
   content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   ```

I've checked the file permissions, and they seem correct. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this **403 Forbidden** error specifically for the `/submissions/` directory on my WordPress site? Any insights or guidance on potential Apache, WordPress, or server configuration issues would be greatly appreciated.

Note: `https://aldenstreetreview.com/submissions/` is not a subdomain